# Quarkus NPE with no args Method

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'am developing a quarkus service, which calls a RestClient-Interface. If I call a RestClient without any args, I get a NullPointer Exception. For example:

```
 @GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
Object getTest();
```

produces a NPE in the following class from "org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.client.ProxyInvocationHandler" (v 4.5.0.Final)

```
 public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
...
int var11 = args.length; //(this causes the NPE)
```

Is there any help on fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`, which functionally equivalent to `quarkus-rest-client`, but is where we are placing all our development efforts going forward. If using this also does not work, please open an issue.

Comment: In my case we can't use it, because we are using Servlet

Comment: The client can be used regardless of what you are using on the server side

Comment: maybe one more question: is there anything similiar regarding the "RestClientAnnotationProviderBuildItem"? I like to enable some annotated classes only with an other custom annotation

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can certainly open an issue asking for this while explaining your use case